# How to put a command that autostart daemon before login in Ubuntu server 20.04

Tags: systemd, ubuntu-20.04

I have two programs in Ubuntu server 20.04, that located in:

```
 /home/kiko/go-btfs/cmd/btfs
 /home/kiko/node5007/cmd/btfs
```

They both run with command: `./btfs daemon` How to make this command for both directories to autostart before login for server? I tried to create autostart service with `sudo nano /etc/systemd/system/btfs_main.service` and then put the following settings in the unit `btfs_main.service`:

```
[Unit]
Description=Starting_btfs_daemon

Wants=network.target
After=syslog.target network-online.target

[Service]
Type=simple
ExecStart=/home/kiko/go-btfs/cmd/btfs/./btfs daemon
ExecStart=/home/kiko/node5007/cmd/btfs/./btfs daemon
Restart=on-failure
RestartSec=10
KillMode=process

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

and then: `sudo systemctl daemon-reload`, `sudo systemctl enable btfs_main.service`, `sudo systemctl start btfs_main.service`, `systemctl status btfs_main.service`. With the final command i have some error: `Unit btfs_main.service has a bad unit file setting`. How do I configure unit settings for the both commands to run automatically?

Comment: you mean login or server reboot? what i can understand is you want your service/code to get run after server reboot.

Comment: Yes, I mean after server reboot in case of power loss for example.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You ca use /etc/rc.local file to start your script after server reboot.

So the steps that you need to go through is as follow:

1. First create `/etc/rc.local` file and make it executable. This cloud be done via `chmod a+x /etc/rc.local` command.
2. Now create `/etc/systemd/system/rc-local.service` file. After creating the systemd service file add the following content to it.

> 

```
[Unit]
 Description=/etc/rc.local Compatibility
 ConditionPathExists=/etc/rc.local

[Service]
 Type=forking
 ExecStart=/etc/rc.local start
 TimeoutSec=0
 StandardOutput=tty
 RemainAfterExit=yes
 SysVStartPriority=99

[Install]
 WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

3. After that, enable the service on system boot:

> **systemctl enable rc-local**

4. Now start the service and check its status:

> **systemctl start rc-local.service**
>
> **systemctl status rc-local.service**

you should get output like below image.
[image]

5. Now put your scripts in the `/etc/rc.local` file and make them executable.
6. Reboot the server and check the results.

Comment: What is the supposed content of `/etc/rc.local` at the very beginning? Is it meant to be created and made executable as an empty file?

Comment: @AdalbertHanßen you make the file executable and put your script which need to be run at boot.